# Is $f(y) = \frac{\sin y}{y}$ a continuous function?

Tags: continuity

Is $f(y) = \frac{\sin y}{y}$ a continuous function?

I am not sure about the point at $y=0$, the denominator cannot be zero but the numerator is also zero! The limit at $y=0$ exists but what about the original function?

Comment: What's the domain of $f$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\sin x/x$ (rather than $f(x)=\sin y/y$)?

Comment: Hint: What is the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$?

Comment: The RHS of the function definition $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is undefined at $x = 0$. However, if you assign a value $1$ to $f(0)$, it will turn it to a continuous function. Since $1$ is the only value which can turn $f(x)$ to a continuous function, when we say $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$, we usually assume $f(0) = 1$ and work with this extension of $f$ from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition says that $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if for all $a \in D$ (the domain of $f$),

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a). $$

So if we're considering continuity at $0$ then first of all $0$ must be in the domain of $f$ and then we're asking if

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0). $$

So you see that we need to say what $f(0)$ is before we can make a decision about whether or not $f$ is continuous at $0$.

So there are two reasonable functions we can consider:

$$ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ defined by } f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}x & x \ne 0 \\
1 & x  = 0
\end{cases} $$

or

$$ f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ defined by } f(x) = \frac{\sin x}x. $$

Both of these functions are continuous. The first is continuous at $0$ because we've defined $f(0)$ as $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$. The second is also continuous at every point in its domain for the simple reason that $0$ is not in its domain.